# Specman - Monitor doesn't recognize events which it is supposed to provide

Tags: monitor, verification, specman

According the Universal Verification Methodology (UVM) e User Guide of Cadence:

The events recognized by the monitor depend on the actual protocol. Typically, for the basic data item the monitor
provides an item_started and an item_ended event (for example, packet_started and packet_ended). The monitor collects
the item data from the signals and creates a current_item that has the complete item data, ready to be used when the
item_ended event occurs. In addition to the raw data, the monitor should collect relevant timing information such as the
duration of the transaction.

I try to execute the following in my agent by:

```
connect_ports() is also {
      uart_monitor.uart_frame_s_started.connect(tx_scb.uart_frame_s_add);
      uart_monitor.uart_frame_s_ended.connect(tx_scb.uart_frame_s_match);
};
```

I get the following errors: Error: 'uart_monitor' (of 'uart_tx_monitor_u') does not have 'uart_frame_S_started'field.... Error: 'uart_monitor' (of 'uart_tx_monitor_u') does not have 'uart_frame_S_ended'field

But when I declare the events in the monitor by:

```
event uart_frame_s_started;
event uart_frame_s_ended;
```

There are no errors.
Why should I declare those events if they are supposed to be provided by the monitor?

Comment: the standard uvm_monitor does not define any event of this fashion. for once , because the data type name is not generic (frame is a protocol specific term, while the uvm_monitor is design for reusability). you need to define those events yourself. nonetheless, you need to define TLM ports to connect to the scoreboard TLM ports. look at the Cadence documentation for more info, or file a support ticket to Cadence support.

Comment: @ yuvalg - as I wrote, I read this in  Universal Verification Methodology (UVM) e User Guide of Cadence specification.

Comment: The definition of 'uart_frame_s_started' is indeed not shown in the documentation, but that does not mean it is defined for you.
please have a look at the UVM examples in the Xcelium installation : Monitor : directory under : <Xcelium directory>/tools/methodology/UVM/CDNS-1.1d/e/uvm_examples/xcore/e/xcore_monitor.e , Scoreboard: <Xcelium directory>/tools/methodology/UVM/CDNS-1.1d/e/uvm_examples/xcore/e/xcore_checker.e.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

are you using the uvm scoreboard? if so, its ports (add and match) are TLM ports. meaning - they expect to get data item written to them.
but you connect to them event ports.

there is something strange - in your code, the events names have a lower 's', but in the error - as you print it - there is capital S. is it uart_frame_s_started or uart_frame_S_started ?

Comment: I trigger the connect with the event. Please look at Universal Verification Methodology (UVM) e User Guide of Cadence specification.  There are some example which demonstrate this. I wrote part of their description in the question.

Comment: for connecting the scoreboard, you have to instantiate TLM ports in the monitor.  the user guide indeed shows just how to connect the ports, but not how they are defined.   if you define the scoreboard as scoreboard of the struct uart_frame, for example, then the monitor has to instantiate ports like " uart_frame_ended : out interface_port of tlm_analysis of packet is instance;", and then connect this port to the scoreboard

Comment: Please look in their example like : `connect_ports() is also {
// Connect the monitors for one flow:
// Agent #1 TX connected to the add port
// Agent #2 RX connected to the match port
agent_1.tx_monitor.packet_ended.connect(scbd.packet_add_1);
agent_2.rx_monitor.packet_ended.connect(scbd.packet_match_1);};` As you can see they using those events in the connect function.